# spelling check for english in sublime

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3

I would like to know how to utilize the spelling check feature in sublime-text.

I have tried the following, however it is not working for me.

What I have

```
perferences.sulime-settings

    {
        "spell_check": false,
        "dictionary": "Packages/Language - English/en_US.dic"

    }
```

if anyone know please help me to found it,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the the spell_check is `true`.

Sublime Text currently only supports UTF-8 encoded dictionaries. Most dictionaries are not encoded in UTF-8, instead using a more compact encoding for the language in question. To use a dictionary with Sublime Text, it'll first need to be converted into UTF-8.

Once you have a UTF-8 encoded dictionary, it can be installed by placing it in a package, for example, Packages/User, which you can access from the Preferences/Browse Packages menu item. Once the file is in place, you can select the dictionary from the View/Dictionary menu.s

```
"spell_check": true,
"dictionary": "Packages/Language - English/en_US.dic"
```

See documenation.
https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/spell_checking.html

Comment: i tried this same from this same link but its not working

Comment: i found solution for this by my self :    (1) cnt+p (2) install package (3) type spell (4) you will see list of packages for spelling you can install whatever you want.